# Android App not supported on many devices

Tags: android

I cant find out why my app is not supported on many devices like Xperia Z or Samsung Galaxy S4 and many more. Especially the newest devices and tablets are not supported.

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.baoss_CDB"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.2.1" >

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<application
    android:name="com.baoss.Misc.MyApplicationContext"
    android:icon="@drawable/cdb"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/cdb"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.baoss.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.baoss.MenuActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
       ...
    <activity
        android:name="com.baoss.SettingTermsOfUseActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

I hope you can help me=).

Comment: you can run `aapt dumb badging` on your APK file and see if there are any implied required features or libraries (if you use jars) that cause the devices to be excluded.

Comment: remove the supports-screens tag? Since you are supporting all screens, it is not necessary to specific again.

Comment: @Calvin really? I have read in the codedoc of google that i should use this tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I can notice is about

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Infact that permission implies `android.hardware.telephony` features, which is generally available just on phones and not in tablets. Try marking that feature as not required:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Don't forget to check at runtime if the current device has phone capability:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)){
    //Add the code for making call
}else{
    //Add the code for devices where telephony is not present, if needed
}
```